# ANT is failing to find org.dbunit.ant.DbUnitTask

Tags: ant, dbunit

So I'm writing a ant build file to run some tests, and I use the following line without any issue for MXUnit:

```
<taskdef name="mxunittask" classname="org.mxunit.ant.MXUnitAntTask" classpath="../mxunit/ant/lib/mxunit-ant.jar"/>
```

But when I download `dbunit-2.4.8.jar` from http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbunit/files/ and put it in the same directory as `mxunit-ant.jar`, then added the following line to the ANT build file:

```
<taskdef name="dbunit" classname="org.dbunit.ant.DbUnitTask" classpath="../mxunit/ant/lib/dbunit-2.4.8.jar"/>
```

For which I see a warning in Eclipse that says:

> taskdef A class needed by class
>   org.dbunit.ant.DbUnitTask cannot be
>   found: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

When I extract the jar file it does have the org.dbunit.ant.DbUnitTask class.. so I'm very confused as to what ANT is complaining about.. any idea what the issue is?

Comment: In your first taskdef you specified a relative classpath, in the second, an absolute one.  You say the jars are in the same directory, but it looks impossible for the two classpaths to be referring to jars in one directory - can you check?

Comment: ah sorry I tried a bunch of paths out actually, I'll edit the above.

Comment: To be more clear I put the `dbunit-2.4.8.jar` file in about 5 different locations, and tried absolute and relative paths, and nothing ever worked (ie: I had the same problem in each case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to make sure all the [dependencies of DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/dependencies.html) are satisfied, as well as installing the dbunit-2.4.8.jar.

The specific error you quote with class `org/slf4j/LoggerFactory` not being found suggests that you don't have the [SLF4J classes](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html) needed.  (Probably the latest version of slf4j-api.jar is needed there.)

Comment: that makes sense, where should I put the jar(s) for SLF4J?

Comment: @Eric - wherever seems suitable - same place as the other jars?  You'll need to add them to the classpath used by Ant, or to that specified in the taskdef.

Comment: "You'll need to add them to the classpath used by Ant, or to that specified in the taskdef." How do I do either of these?

Comment: ahh this might help me: http://j2eeframeworks.blogspot.com/2008/10/problems-in-integrating-ant-with-dbunit.html I'll try soon

Comment: @Erik - Looks old, but gist will be same - Eclipse/Ant/Classpath: http://onjava.com/onjava/excerpt/anttdg2_ch11/index1.html.

Comment: @Erik - Setting the classpath for a taskdef only, you would set a classpath before the taskdef with a reference id, then refer to it in the taskdef using the classpathref attribute.  See the typedef docs as a starting point: http://onjava.com/onjava/excerpt/anttdg2_ch11/index1.html

Comment: @Erik - that link looks useful too.